# how to call api and load the data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At what i am trying to do is in my below code.i have one table and when i select the row and then click find button then data is not fetched in api .

and i m trying to do in my below code when i select row and click button then I am not get data in console

I need to make api call on button click how can we do that

I need to call this api on button click https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e

my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-o8tu5

Comment: Any one idea about that api call in react?? I m stuck on that

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are attempting to make the API call-- you just have a URL in a comment at the bottom of your code.

Comment: Check out the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Thanks for reply@Alexander  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-o8tu5 in this my code I have one button and I need to make on click button api call  this is the api https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e

Comment: Yes I tried but I m not getting solution. Can u help m out @Henry

Comment: Can u show me something in my code it's very thankful

Answer (score 1):

Check this example. I have modified your code to make you understand the way.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      row: ''
    };
  }
  selectList = (selected) => {
    this.setState({row: selected});
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(`call APi here: ${this.state.row}`)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="table-employee"
          style={{ marginTop: "20px", border: " 1.5px solid darkgray" }}
        >
          <table onClick={() => this.selectList('First')} className="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Select</th>
                <th scope="col"> LOAD DATE</th>
                <th scope="col"> FILE DATE</th>
                <th scope="col"> SERVICE</th>
                <th scope="col"> PROVISIONER CODE </th>
                <th scope="col"> DESCRIPTION</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="radio" preventDefault name="select" />
                </td>

                <td>dfgrty</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>erer</td>
                <td>uuio</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="btn-submit">
          <button
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={{ marginRight: "30px" }}
            type="submit"
          >
            submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-sjn7j)

Comment: Thanks to this but in here when I click alert is showing. I want to show data in console.

Comment: Can we do that to show data in console?? @akhtarvahid

Comment: https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e this is api

Comment: @shivanipandey sure i'll send you sample app as live application using your API.